# Find the area of the surface defined by $x-y-z=1$ and $2x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area, greens-theorem

> Find the area of the surface defined by $x-y-z=1$ and $2x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

I've tried to solve this using Green's theorem, but I'm not getting the correct answer.

The curve I get when I intersect those two surfaces is $2x^2+y^2=1$, so I get the parametric equation $\alpha(t)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos(t), \sin(t))$ with $t \in [0, 2\pi]$.

And I choose the field $X(x,y)=(0,x)$ such that $Q_x-P_y=0$, where $Q=x$ and $P=0$

So, by Green's theorem: $A(S)=\int\int _{S} dA = \int _{0} ^{2\pi} X(\alpha(t)) \cdot \alpha'(t) dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int _{0} ^{2\pi} \cos^2(t)dt=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$, which is incorrect

> The correct answer is $\frac{\sqrt3\pi}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Have you seen the surface area formula $\int_R\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}dA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surface of the plane $x-y-z=1$ inside the elliptic cylinder $\frac{x^2}{(1/\sqrt2)^2} + \frac{y^2}{1^2} = 1$ $\, (a = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}, b = 1)$.

What you are doing is parametrizing your surface to find its area. I am not sure why you called you were applying Green's theorem. The part you missed was parametrizing your plane.

Parametrization of the plane is $z = f(x,y) = x-y - 1$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -1$

$\sqrt{1+( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^2} = \sqrt3$. This has to be part of your surface area integral. In this case, it is a constant so you can multiply it after your integral.

So the desired surface area $= \sqrt{3} \times A \,$ where $A$ is the area of the ellipse in $XY$ plane. You already calculated $A$ correctly.

Or we also know that area of ellipse is given by $A = \pi \, a \, b = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Thank you! I really don't know why I got Green's theorem mixed up...

Comment: I would say you are not entirely incorrect. One can look at the trick that way. You just have to be careful when the surface is 3D that you are converting that correctly. You did most of the part. The part that you missed was the projection of the surface in 3D on XY plane.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is an oval with primary axes of length $2$ and $\sqrt{6}$, so by the formula for the area of an elliptical region the answer is $\sqrt{3/2} \pi$.